# Problem with android studio and public classes/attributes

Tags: java, android-studio

I'll put here a practical example of what's happening because it is some time now I'm trying to resolve with no results.

This is a public class for those methods/attributes I need in different activities or java files:

```
package com.mgs.bchat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Util {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "BChat MSG";
    public static final String SP_NAME = "BChatSharedPreferences";
    public static final String SAVED_NICKNAME = "BChatSPSavedNickname";
    public static final String INTENT_PARCELABLE = "BChatParcelableGeneric";
    public static final String INTENT_DEVICE_NAME = "BChatParcelableName";
    public static final String INTENT_DEVICE_MAC = "BChatParcelableMac";

    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
    public static final String DEVICE = "device_name";

    public static void SimpleToast(Context context, String msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

This is a call of one of those member variables

```
package com.mgs.bchat;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Handler.Callback;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.msg.bchat.Util;

import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;

import static com.mgs.bchat.Util.MESSAGE_WRITE;

public interface ChatHandler extends Handler.Callback {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage( Message message) {
        switch (message.what){
            case Util.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (message.arg1){
                    case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        setStatus(getString(R.string.stateConnected)+ connectingDevice.getName());
                        break;
 
                       .
                       .
                       .
    
    }
}
```

I have to either, use the class.attr notation or do an import per attribute, like the one above

```
import static com.mgs.bchat.Util.MESSAGE_WRITE;
```

automatically created by android studio when including MESSAGE_WRITE by pressing ALT+Enter.

Now, MESSAGE_WRITE is public, in a public class, and it's used in a public interface (but you know it could be a private interface/class also, it wouldn't make a difference). If this was plain java, I'd had no problems, but android studio seems to not like java access specifier and packages.
Why I can't just type MESSAGE_WRITE like I would do in java, but instead I have to recall its class or import the damn attribute?

I'm going crazy for this, please help me. I know how access specifier and visibility works in java, and this case in a mystery for me, please proof me I'm an idiot for not being able to read or tell me is a freaking bug/"feature" of android studio

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your package specification you have a typo. You import msg, but package name is mgs.

Comment: By using:
import static com.mgs.bchat.util.*;
i can use the static attributes. I feel dumb for not having tried this before (probably I used static, but I've made some other mistakes). Thank you so much

Comment: @samuele55598 you can accept the answer if it helped you. The is a Vi sign near it.